# A gerrymandering problem - can you always turn a tie into a landslide victory?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

*Note: Here we use $|A|$ to denote the Lebesgue measure of a measurable subset $A$ of $\mathbb R^2$.*

Your party is running for election! In your country, voters are approximately uniformly distributed. Given at least half of the voters voted for you, can you divide the country into $N$ equally sized regions such that your party wins the majority vote in all but one?

Formally, let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^2$ be a bounded, simply connected open set, and $E$ a measurable subset of $\Omega$ with $|E| \geq \frac{|\Omega|}{2}$.

We say a finite collection of open sets $A_i$ is an *almost partition* of $\Omega$ if the $A_i$ are disjoint, and $\overline \Omega = \cup_i A_i \bigcup \cup_i \partial A_i$.

**Question:** Let $N \geq 3$ be arbitrary. Does there always exist a almost partition of $\Omega$ into simply connected open sets $A_1, \dots, A_N$, each of measure $\frac{|\Omega|}{N}$ such that for all $1 \leq i \leq N-1$, we have $|E \cap A_i| > \frac{|A_i|}{2}?$

Comment: I suppose you could repeatedly apply IVT as they do here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685220/divide-a-finite-measure-set-into-two-part-of-equal-measure-using-one-hyperplane 

"A is a measurable set in $\mathbb R^n$ with finite measure, the goal is to prove that there exists a real number $r$ with $m(A \cap\{x:x_n<r\})=m(A\cap\{x:x_n>r\})$, where $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ in $\mathbb R^n$."

Comment: here too https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840045/partition-a-set-in-mathbb-r2-into-equal-measure-sets

Comment: https://www.colorado.edu/economics/sites/default/files/attached-files/pancs.pdf (and the references therein) might be relevant.

Comment: I just feel that there should be some connection to the Ham Sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the almost partition exists. Instead of letting $\mu(E)\geq\frac{\mu(\Omega)}{2}$, I let $\mu(E)\in(0,\mu(\Omega))$ be arbitrary and proved that you can divide $\Omega$ into $N$ open simply connected districts $S',S_2,\dots,S_N$ of measure $\frac{\mu(\Omega)}{N}$ such that $\mu(S'\cap E)<\frac{\mu(E)}{N}<\mu(S_2\cap E)=\dots=\mu(S_N\cap E)$.

**Lemma:** Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on the open unit disk $D^2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_(measure_theory)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20and%20specifically%20in,which%20events%20have%20measure%20zero.) to Lebesgue measure, let $E\subseteq D^2$ be a measurable set and let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then we can find a [disk sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector) $S\subseteq D^2$ with $\mu(S)=\frac{\mu(D^2)}{n}$ and $\mu(S\cap E)=\frac{\mu(E)}{n}$.

**Proof of the lemma:** Let $f:[0,2\pi]$ be defined by $f(x)=\mu(\{z\in D^2;\text{arg}(z)\in(0,x)\})$. Then $f$ is a continuous function with $f(0)=0$ and $f(2\pi)=\mu(D^2)$. Now for each $t\in\left[0,\mu(D^2)-\frac{\mu(D^2)}{n}\right]$ let $S(t)$ be the sector $\left\{z\in D^2;\text{arg}(z)\in\left(f^{-1}(t),f^{-1}\left(t+\frac{\mu(D^2)}{n}\right)\right)\right\}$, so that $\mu(S(t))=\frac{\mu(D^2)}{n}$ for all $t$.

Note that $\mu(E\cap S(t))$ varies continuously, and at some point it has to be exactly $\frac{\mu(E)}{n}$: this is thanks to the intermediate value theorem and the fact that $\mu(E\cap S(0))+\mu(E\cap S(\frac{\mu(D^2)}{n}))+\dots+\mu(E\cap S(\frac{(n-1)\mu(D^2)}{n}))=\mu(E)$, due to $S(0),S(\frac{\mu(D^2)}{n})),\dots,S(\frac{(n-1)\mu(D^2)}{n}))$ being an almost partition of the disk. $\square$

Now let's return to the original problem. We can suppose that $\Omega$ is a disk and $\mu$ is some measure in $\Omega$ equivalent to Lebesgue measure, thanks to the Riemann mapping theorem. By the lemma there is a sector $S\subseteq\Omega$ with $\mu(S)=\frac{\mu(\Omega)}{N}$ and $\mu(S\cap E)=\frac{\mu(E)}{N}$. We can transform this sector a bit into a set $S'$ such that $\mu(S')=\frac{\mu(D^2)}{N}$ and $\mu(S'\cap E)<\frac{\mu(E)}{N}$: to do it, let $p\in S$ and $q\in D^2\setminus\overline{S}$ be such that $E$ has density $1$ in $p$ and $0$ in $q$. Now take very small balls $B_p,B_q$ around $p,q$, remove $B_p$ from $S$ and add $B_q$ to $S$. We can ensure that $S'$ and $D^2\setminus\overline{S'}$ are simply connected by joining $B_p$ to $D^2\setminus\overline{S}$ and $B_q$ to $S$ by small neighborhoods of curves (both neighborhoods can be taken to have the same area, so that $\mu(S')$ remains $\frac{\mu(D^2)}{N}$, and they can have area as small as we want, so that the inequality $\mu(S'\cap E)<\frac{\mu(E)}{N}$ is still satisfied).

The set $S'$ will be the only district where out party loses the majority vote. Let $\Omega_1=D^2\setminus\overline{S'}$, which is simply connected. Note that $\mu(S')=\frac{\mu(X)}{N}$, and we have $\frac{\mu(E\cap\Omega_1)}{\mu(\Omega_1)}>\frac{\mu(E)}{\mu(X)}$. By the lemma we can find an open simply connected subset $S_2$ of $\Omega_1$ such that $\mu(S_2)=\frac{\mu(\Omega)}{N}=\frac{\mu(\Omega_1)}{N-1}$ and $\frac{\mu(E\cap S_2)}{\mu(S_2)}=\frac{\mu(E\cap\Omega_1)}{\mu(\Omega_1)}$, and so that $\Omega_2=\Omega_1\setminus\overline{S_2}$ is simply connected. But then we also have $\frac{\mu(E\cap\Omega_2)}{\mu(\Omega_2)}=\frac{\mu(E\cap\Omega_1)}{\mu(\Omega_1)}$, so we can create $S_3$ using the lemma, etc.

At the end we are left with a sequence of districts $S',S_2,\dots,S_N=\Omega_{N-1}$ of measure $\frac{\mu(\Omega)}{N}$ such that
$$\frac{\mu(E\cap S')}{\mu(S')}<\frac{\mu(E)}{\mu(\Omega)}<\frac{\mu(E\cap\Omega_1)}{\mu(\Omega_1)}=\frac{\mu(E\cap S_2)}{\mu(S_2)}=\dots=\frac{\mu(E\cap S_N)}{\mu(S_N)},$$
which after multiplying by $\frac{\mu(\Omega)}{N}$ becomes what we wanted:
$\mu(S'\cap E)<\frac{\mu(E)}{N}<\mu(S_2\cap E)=\dots=\mu(S_N\cap E)$.

Comment: Thank you for the juicy looking answer. I will read it more thoroughly when I am free tomorrow.

Comment: Just managed to read it, what a nice solution. Now I’m imagining some gerrymanderer constructing these regions via the algorithm…

Comment: Haha. I don't know how explicit the Riemann mapping theorem is. By the way, I think stronger statements could be made, e.g. for any set $E$, for any $\varepsilon$, and for an appropriate number of districts, we can likely gerrymander so that the set of districts in which $E$ adds up to a measure $>(2-\varepsilon)\mu(E)$. So in particular, if $\mu(E)>\mu(\Omega)/4$ and the number of districts is even, then I think we could make $E$ win the election. But that would require a more complicated argument